# Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function

Tags: t-sql

I have written the query and it is working:

```
declare @word as nvarchar (20)
set @word = 'victOR aALEXander'
select upper(left(@word, 1)) + lower(SUBSTRING(@word,2,charindex(' ', @word)-2)) + ' ' + 
upper(left(substring(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+1,len(@word)-1),1)) 
+ lower(SUBSTRING(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+2, len(@word)))
```

I have created the function:

```
  alter function letters ( @word as nvarchar(20))
returns varchar(20) as begin
return upper(left(@word, 1)) + lower(SUBSTRING(@word,2,charindex(' ', @word)-2)) + ' ' + 
upper(left(substring(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+1,len(@word)-1),1)) 
+ lower(SUBSTRING(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+2, len(@word))) end
```

Finally i have done:

```
select dbo.letters(users)
from dbo.tempdb
```

I have got:

Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function

Why?

Comment: A blogged several years ago about a proper case function.  There are a lot of people all over the world using it.  I suggest that you at least give it a try.  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/sql-server-proper-case-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
Create Function dbo.Proper(@Data VarChar(8000))
Returns VarChar(8000)
As
Begin
  Declare @Position Int

  Select @Data = Stuff(Lower(@Data), 1, 1, Upper(Left(@Data, 1))),
         @Position = PatIndex('%[^a-zA-Z][a-z]%', @Data COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin)

  While @Position > 0
    Select @Data = Stuff(@Data, @Position, 2, Upper(SubString(@Data, @Position, 2))),
           @Position = PatIndex('%[^a-zA-Z][a-z]%', @Data COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin)

  Return @Data
End
```

This function works properly whether there are spaces, apostrophes, or anything else in your data.  Unfortunately it won't convert macdonald to MacDonald or o'brien to O'Brien.  However, it will work for any word(s) that only have 1 capital letter in it.

Answer (score 0):

Character count of `@word` parameter is less than substring count. Also, parameter could be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

also try trimming in case you have spaces at the beginning and end:

```
alter function letters ( @word as nvarchar(20))
returns varchar(20) as 
begin
set @word = ltrim(rtrim(@word))
return upper(left(@word, 1)) + lower(SUBSTRING(@word,2,charindex(' ', @word)-2)) + ' ' + 
upper(left(substring(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+1,len(@word)-1),1)) 
+ lower(SUBSTRING(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+2, len(@word))) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try if this query works. However if you have more than single ' ' then this query will fail.

```
declare @word as nvarchar (20)

set @word = 'alex' -- 'victOR aALEXander'

select 
upper(left(@word, 1)) + 
CASE WHEN charindex(' ', @word)>0 THEN  lower(SUBSTRING(@word,2,charindex(' ', @word)-2)) + ' '
+ upper(left(substring(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+1,len(@word)-1),1)) 
+ lower(SUBSTRING(@word,charindex(' ', @word)+2, len(@word)))
 ELSE lower(SUBSTRING(@word,2,len(@word)-1)) END
```